# Second screen tearing AMD Radeon 5800 HD Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, radeon, tearing

Well, I've been trying to get this work for a while...

The second screen doesn't stop tearing.

I'm using "AMD Catalyst™ 13.1 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver" which was install according to:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Generate_a_new_.2Fetc.2FX11.2Fxorg.conf_file

1. I also installed "Additional Drivers", and tried the X.Org X server driver, but its performance are embarrassing.

   2. I checked "Tear Free" option in the Catalyst config GUI.
   3. I also unchecked Sync to VBlank CompizConfig.
      (As suggested in [How to get AMD graphics card working well 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191941/how-to-get-amd-graphics-card-working-well-12-04) )

Non of this seem to help.

Does anyone got a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the few who also use an HD 5800 card (5830) with Ubuntu in a dual screen configuration. I had the exact same problems as you when I started, and wracked my brains trying to solve it with very little response from the forums.

Several months later I am hanging in there, and managed to solve the problems well enough, but I still lack the ability to do fairly normal things on more common operating systems: play HD videos, scroll quickly down a document/webpage with tearing ect... If you are still looking for help, I might be able to get you as far as I have come (much better).

I have to say, having done it alone, I would go as far as to recommend selling that 5800 series GPU while there is a strong market for it, and buying something else. I am using the Ubuntu provided fglrx repository, and I about to test the xvba-video package. Perhaps this (and emerging gaming on linux focus) will lend some more function for our otherwise awesome video cards.

Here is some information:

Xorg.conf

```
  Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    EndSection
  Section "Module"
    EndSection
  Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    EndSection
  Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1920 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
    EndSection
  Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP2" "0-DFP2"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    EndSection
  Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
    EndSection
  Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Virtual   3200 3200
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
    EndSection
  Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

fglrxinfo:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series  
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.00.11
```

Next we can work out the Catalyst Control Center settings if you decide you want to keep the card.
Good luck =)