# How do I revert the AMD driver to a previous working state?

Tags: ati

I was trying to see if I was using the AMD proprietary driver for my card, and I opted to use the AMD driver without updates instead of the one with updates. My GUI crashed, and now I can't get an x-server to start or even get to a terminal that I can revert the drivers. Has anyone had this experience that knows what I can do?

Comment: Alright, so for documentation purposes, I followed these instructions:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/191941/how-to-get-amd-graphics-card-working-well-12-04?rq=1

Comment: I managed to access a terminal through grub, I had to run it in graphics safe mode, which failed, but that put it into read/write mode, so I could remove the package from the terminal. I'm sure there's an easier way straight from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have this question answered, I had to switch grub to read/write mode and out of read mode before I could use the "emergency" terminal and [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191941/how-to-get-amd-graphics-card-working-well-12-04?rq=1). I did this by selecting another option under the recovery option, I don't remember which one, but although it failed I was able to get into read/write mode to uninstall and reinstall the driver.